# Funs() and related errors

Tags: r

I'm trying to replicate the example code here https://garberadamc.github.io/project-site/Lab8-Intro-mixture

However, I'm having an issue with the very first step, I know that funs() is deprecated, and so is mutate_all. I tried replacing funs() with list and mutate_all with mutate_across, and I wasn't able to get the first few lines of code working. I don't really even understand what this line of the code is doing. Could someone please explain and suggest an alternative?

```
data(cheating)
cheating <- cheating %>% clean_names() 

df_cheat <-  cheating %>%                                  
 dplyr::select(1:4) %>%                                   
 dplyr::mutate_all(funs(.-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `mutate_all` code with `across` as -

```
library(dplyr)

cheating %>%                     
  dplyr::select(1:4) %>%         
  dplyr::mutate_all(funs(.-1)) -> res1

cheating %>%
  dplyr::select(1:4) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(across(.fns = ~. - 1)) -> res2

identical(res1, res2)
#[1] TRUE
```